# K-fold cross validation dealing with an interaction term

Tags: regression, logistic, cross-validation

I'm working on a logistic regression analysis and have a data set that contains ~12,000 data values (~6,000 values = 1; ~6,000 values = 0). I would like to use a k-fold cross validation process to validate my model. However, I have an interaction term in my model:

```
results<-glmer(R0A1~MP_Scaled*Season1+MPHW_Scaled*Season1+HW_Scaled*Season1+YP_Scaled*Season1+AG_Scaled*Season1+Shrub_Scaled*Season1+(1|ID)+(1|Site),data=turkey2nd,family=binomial, glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)))
```

I found the following R code to conduct a k-fold cross-validation procedure:

```
library(boot)
turkey <- read.csv(file.choose())
results <- glm(R0A1~MP_Scaled+MPHW_Scaled+HW_Scaled+YP_Scaled+AG_Scaled+Shrub_Scaled,data=turkey2nd,family=binomial(link="logit"))
cost <- function(r,pi=0)mean(abs(r-pi)>0.5)
output <- cv.glm(turkey,results,cost,K=10)
output$delta
```

My resulting delta estimate was 0.42. This seems like a very poor model validation value (less than a flip of a coin). What suggestions could I use to improve model performance? Thanks!

Comment: Your question's title seems unrelated to the question. It appears you want to know how to improve your model, which is orthogonal to doing cross-validation. The interaction terms also don't affect cross-validation.

Comment: @MarcClaesen, sorry for the lack of clarity in my post. I really am not sure  how the interaction term would affect the validation process and thought that it may be affecting the delta estimate.